# Handled exception causes an AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, access-violation, hangfire

I would like to ask for help with a C# API Project, to be more specific, an exception that have been giving issues for some pretty long time now. Currently the projects runs on .NET Core 3.1 and it uses Hangfire.

Basically, the problem is that back when we used Visual Studio 2019, whenever we had any handled exception the application would keep running just fine, however once we updated to Visual Studio 2022, any throw exception in development environment will make the application stop giving us usually two exceptions. Lets suppose a NullReferenceException has happened, right after it the application would keep running, however we get a System.AccessViolationException:

[image: System.AccessViolationException]

That's the issue, the AccessViolationException will make the application stop despite the exception that caused it (NullReferenceException for example) be a handled exception.

Enabling native code debugging doesn't help much since it will just mention that the exception thrown will be at the KernelBase.dll.

I read somewhere that enabling Microsoft Symbols Servers in Options->Debugging->Symbols may give more details into this exception, but enabling it either makes the application not start or makes it starts way too slowly.

This doesn't happen with some of our other projects. Not sure if it has anything to do with it, but that other project doesn't use Hangfire and runs in .NET Core 3.1. Weirdly, other computers that runs the same project, on the same OS, on VS2022 doesn't have such issue.

So far we've tried to reinstall the .NET Core Sdks, reinstall VS2022, installing the same Sdk that the working computers have and even downgrading to VS2019 (where it used to work). None of them have worked. Did anyone went through this or had something similar?

Comment: Are you able to post any of the code involved?
If not, try to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Also, try putting a breakpoint on your catch statements and see what happens.  

Since you're using hangfire, it could also be caused by having multiple threads modifying the same memory at the same time; that's usually the cause of exceptions like this.

Comment: The issue also happens whenever we execute any simple API calls, even if Hangfire is not set to start up. In the main post I just thought it was useful to mention because it may have something to do with the issue (in case someone experienced the same problem).

Comment: Have you found any solution to this problem yet? I'm facing exactly the same issue and can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Nope, so far nothing. If you do find a solution for this issue, please tell me.

Comment: I have a peculiarly similar scenario: we just upgraded an API project from 4.7.2 to Core 3.1 and I'm now also getting `AccessViolationException`'s after other exceptions are thrown, specifically when accessing the exception's `StackTrace` property. Have tried trimming down my project heavily to see if some external dependency was causing it but thus far have not found anything.